# How to get JS variable to retain value after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to permanently change a javascript variable? As in, if I set the variable X and make that equal to 1. Then onClick of a button change that variable to 2. How can I get that variable to stay at 2 on refresh of the page?

Answer (score 309, accepted):

This is possible with `window.localStorage` or `window.sessionStorage`. The difference is that `sessionStorage` lasts for as long as the browser stays open, `localStorage` survives past browser restarts.  The persistence applies to the *entire web site* not just a single page of it.

When you need to set a variable that should be reflected in the next page(s), use:

```
var someVarName = "value";
localStorage.setItem("someVarKey", someVarName);
```

And in any page (like when the page has loaded), get it like:

```
var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("someVarKey");
```

`.getItem()` will return `null` if no value stored, or the value stored.

Note that **only string values** can be stored in this storage, but this can be overcome by using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. Technically, whenever you call `.setItem()`, it will call `.toString()` on the value and store that.

MDN's DOM storage guide (linked below), has workarounds/polyfills, that end up falling back to stuff like cookies, if `localStorage` isn't available.

It wouldn't be a bad idea to use an existing, or create your own mini library, that abstracts the ability to save any data type (like object literals, arrays, etc.).

---

**References:**

- Browser `Storage` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage
- `localStorage` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage
- `JSON` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON
- Browser Storage compatibility - http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage
- Storing objects - [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: `localStorage` doesn't seem to be working in private browsing mode in iOS devices. Reference [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555347/html5-localstorage-error-with-safari-quota-exceeded-err-dom-exception-22-an]

Comment: @lan JSON.stringify doesn't preserver our functions, how can we solve this?

Comment: Yeah no magic..just use local storage

Answer (score 37):

In addition to cookies and `localStorage`, there's at least one other place you can store  "semi-persistent" client data: `window.name`. Any string value you assign to `window.name` will stay there until the window is closed.

To test it out, just open the console and type `window.name = "foo"`, then refresh the page and type `window.name`; it should respond with `foo`.

This is a bit of a hack, but if you don't want cookies filled with unnecessary data being sent to the server with every request, and if you can't use `localStorage` for whatever reason (legacy clients), it may be an option to consider.

`window.name` has another interesting property: it's visible to windows served from other domains; it's not subject to the same-origin policy like nearly every other property of `window`. So, in addition to storing "semi-persistent" data there while the user navigates or refreshes the page, you can also use it for CORS-free cross-domain communication.

Note that `window.name` can only store strings, but with the wide availability of `JSON`, this shouldn't be much of an issue even for complex data.

Comment: I see you sneaking in here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567847/window-name-as-a-data-transport-a-valid-approach :)

Comment: @Ian lol, good catch. I don't know why, but I'm sort of fascinated with `window.name`

Comment: I'm very interested now! That all sounds familiar, but I'm not sure I knew about this feature. I knew about setting the `name` with `window.open`, but that's as far as I ever took it

Comment: In my scenario, the parameter must not persist across tabs or browser windows, just across page calls in the current open window. For that, window.name works perfect!

Answer (score 8):

You will have to use cookie to store the value across page refresh. You can use any one of the many javascript based cookie libraries to simplify the cookie access, like [this one](https://code.google.com/p/cookies/)

If you want to support only html5 then you can think of [Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) api like [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute)/[sessionStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-sessionstorage-attribute)

Ex: using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage#localStorage) and [cookies library](https://code.google.com/p/cookies/)

```
var mode = getStoredValue('myPageMode');

function buttonClick(mode) {
    mode = mode;
    storeValue('myPageMode', mode);
}

function storeValue(key, value) {
    if (localStorage) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    } else {
        $.cookies.set(key, value);
    }
}

function getStoredValue(key) {
    if (localStorage) {
        return localStorage.getItem(key);
    } else {
        return $.cookies.get(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by storing cookies on client side.