# How to retain radio input state on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a form on which i need to store the state of all radio buttons if a user submit the form with errors (which in case the page would refresh).

I want to achieve something quite similar to this:

```
$(function(){
        $('.example input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
        $(this).attr("checked",true);
    });
```

Any help would much be appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to use cookies or HTML 5 local storage, or have the server generate new HTML based on the `POST` data.  Lots of options, pretty common problem.  What's your server-side technology?

Comment: using any kind of persistent data client side as cookie or localStorage

Comment: Look here, I think this old post can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh

Comment: before submit you can perform validations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could store it's state within local storage and restore it after each page load.

Little example on storing the value:

```
$('#myCheckbox').click(function () {
    localStorage['my.checkbox'] = this.checked;
});
```

Restore it:

```
$('#myCheckbox').prop('checked', localStorage['my.checkbox'] == 'true');
```

Comment: Could you please help with the coding. I have added myformID to the onclick, but doest seem to work..

Comment: And yes, there are about 20 radio buttons on that form :)

Comment: You will need to bind the click event to the radio element so you can save it's checked state on each click. You will need write another little script to restore those values on load.

Comment: can you please advise what i did wrong in this code, since it is not working:   if(Modernizr.localstorage){
   $('input[type="radio"]).click(function(){
    localStorage["key"] = this.checked;
   });
   $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked' localStorage["key"]=='true');
   
  }

Comment: I can tell you missed a `,` between the arguments in `prop()`.

Comment: i've put the "," but no real success :(

Comment: Since there are many input radios, is a loop not needed here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37924/discussion-between-bart-and-wasiim)

Comment: I managed to get it working, had to make a tweak with my selector. However, i have one issue now, the if i refesh the page multiple times(if i submit the form multiple time with errors), only the state of the FIRST submit is retained!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you store the information in the session token or in a session cookie. If you use html5 components, you might try to use html local storage.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to update the code

```
$(function(){
        $('.example input[type="radio"]').each(function(){
           $(this).attr("checked",$(this).checked());
    });
```

It will save the property of radio button as user has selected for the radio button.