# Remember position of a div on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, draggable

I am using a code that allows for a div to be moved on click wherever the user wants to on the page. http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/

What I want to do, however, is for the browser/webpage to remember where the user dragged the cbox to so it will stay there after refreshing the page. Right now, if you move it, when you refresh it puts it back to where it started. I figured this is done via cookies but I can't think of where to start to accomplish this.

http://candyland-couture.com The chat box on the bottom left is the moveable div I'm referring to. It is draggable by hovering over the purple banner above it and clicking and dragging.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh

Comment: I tried using this, but I couldn't figure out how to add it into my code. A demo of it's implementation would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage). Save the coordinates of the div (`top` and `left`
 perhaps) inside it. Another option would be cookies but for something this simple localStorage might be the better fit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function like this one, to save the coordinates to a cookie:

```
$("#moveme").draggable({
  // Find position where element is dropped.
  stop: function(event, ui) {
    // Show dropped position.
    var Stoppos = $(this).position();
    console.log("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top);
    //Save the values to cookie o localStorage
    //I'm gonna use jquery cookie plugin
    $.cookie("left",Stoppos.left);
    $.cookie("top",Stoppos.top);
  }
});
```

Then when you refresh the page, if those cookies exists and their values are not empty, you set the values on your element:

```
$("#moveme").css({top: $.cookie("top"), left: $.cookie("left")});
```

You should include the plugin in your website, so here it is: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.js

Comment: I added these in and it didn't work. Still pops back to where it starts.

Comment: I looked in your site code and you have at least 4 different version of jquery include in it...and 2 version of jquery.cookie too