# Javascript - Option select with jQuery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want users to select an option from the drop down menu. The HTML goes like this:

```
<option value="111">AAA</option>
<option value="222">BBB</option>
<option value="333">CCC</option>`
```

When the page first loads, this is called:

```
query.auid = $('#tabs' option:selected').prop('value');
```

And it selects the first value as the default from the drop down menu. Now when the user selects another option and when the page reloads, it resets back to default value. I want to save the last selected value by the user even after page reloads. How do I achieve this?

Comment: With cookies or localstorage

Comment: You can subscribe for an event of changing option and write changes to your object.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh

Comment: Thank you for a direction...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the value in HTML5Local Storage..
[**HTML5 Storage**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)