# Javascript variable loses value

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with a static variable. If the page is refreshed, the last value of the variable is lost. This is the code:

```
var ok;

alert(ok);

if(ok==1) {
$('tr:has(td:contains("Blue"))').hide()
}

$('tr:has(td:contains("Blue"))').delay(10000).hide(0)
    ok=1;   

alert(ok);
```

Comment: You are kidding right?

Comment: What did you expect ?

Comment: Do you know how javascript works? Why do you think it would save everything you're doing? Do you know how computers work? Why do you think rebooting a computer fixes quite a few issues? (*hint; because all it knew, except for what is **specifically remembered** is forgotten, just like javascript*)

Answer (score 3):

> If the page is refreshed, the last value of the variable is lost.

When the page is refreshed, all the values stored in that **window's session** is lost and a new sesssion is created.

Unless you store the values in your browser's storage, you are not going to retain them.

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh a page, all stored values are lost thought its possible to retain the variable value.This is possible with `window.localStorage` (or `window.sessionStorage`). The difference is explained at MDN's DOM storage guide (linked below).

When you need to set a variable that should be reflected in the next page(s), use:

```
var someVarName = "value";

localStorage.setItem("someVarName", someVarName);
```

And in any page (like when the page has loaded), get it like:

```
 var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
```

`.getItem()` will return null or the value stored.

Note that only string values can be stored in this storage, but this can be overcome by using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. Technically, whenever you call `.setItem()`, it will call `.toString()` on the value and store that.

MDN's DOM storage guide (linked below), has workarounds/polyfills, that end up falling back to stuff like cookies, if `localStorage` isn't available.

It wouldn't be a bad idea to use an existing, or create your own mini library, that abstracts the ability to save any data type (like object literals, arrays, etc.).

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh