# How to keep hidden a div after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following div called "load". I would like to keep it hidden when you refresh the site. However, this div should be showed every time you land on the page (first time or not first time).

Is it possible? How?

Thanks

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
    }, 2500);
  }
}
```

```css
#load {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  background-color: #29d4e6;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  -o-animation-delay: 2.3s;
  animation-delay: 2.3s;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="animated fadeOut" id="load"></div>
  <div> Hello there! </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try setting a Cookie ,LocalStorage or can store the first time counter in your database if you are using any login for your webpage.

Comment: i have edited the answer check that i should work...

Answer (score 0):

Use `onbeforeunload` events in Browser for detecting the refresh button and `localStorage` for storing refresh status

```
document.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var state = document.readyState
  if (state == 'complete') {
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById('interactive');
      document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";

    }, 2500);
<!-- this will hide the #load when you refresh the page --!>

window.onbeforeunload = refresh;

function refresh()
{           
localStorage.refresh=1;
}

if(localStorage.refresh==1)
{
document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
localStorage.refresh=0;
}


}
```

This will show the div every time you land on the page whether first time or not  but wont show if you refresh the page .

Comment: This does not solve the **"However, this div should be showed every time you land on the page"**

Comment: how about this??

Answer (score 0):

Set a `sessionStorage` variable. `sessionStorage` variables are stored only for the browsing session and won't reset if the page is refreshed unless you willingly reset them.

```
 var i;
 if(state == 'complete') {
     setTimeout(function() {
         document.getElementById('interactive');
         document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
     }, 2500);
     sessionStorage.setItem('i','true');
 }
```

Then use,

```
 var s = sessionStorage.getItem('i');
```

to get the value and check if it's set or true or a specified value. Check the variable before you call the `load` animation.

Reference:

[How to get JS variable to retain value after page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh)

[Global Variable usage on page reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload)

Comment: Hello @bowl0stu I have tried it, but it doesn't work or maybe I don't how to use it.

Comment: My code is not complete; just an example. Look at the links I referenced to learn more about them.

Answer (score -1):

You can hide div when page load using javascript.
Like

```
$(function(){
    $("#load").hide();

});
```

Comment: Your contribution is valid, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: okay then just write hidden in div like                                                              <div id='load' hidden>  @bowl0stu can try this

Comment: That still doesn't answer the original question. The first time you visit the page, `<div id="load">` needs to show. If you were to refresh the page, `<div id="load">` needs to be hidden. Your code and comment set the ready state to `hidden` and `display` property to `hidden` instead of a viable solution for displaying `<div id="load">` once the first time you visit the page.

Answer (score -1):

I can only think of two way to accomplish this. One is to maintain a session variable on the server to know that the page has been hit, and pass a variable the first time to the page to know that it should make the div visible.
Or two, using a session cookie to accomplish the same thing. Creating a session cookie and creating a variable to indicate that the users has already visited that page during this session.