# Javascript: Global Variables Aren't Defined In Other Functions

Tags: javascript

I have three variables that I need to put in the `innerHTML` of four spans. The variables I use are `seconds`, `accurateclick`, and `inaccurateclick`. The process I use to get these variables is fine. The problem is I can't figure out how to bring them over to another function. I will make a replica of what I have. This will be a simpler version.

```
var x;
var y;
var z;

function A(){
    x = 1;
    y = 2;
    z = 3;
    B();
}

function B(){
    var a = "";
    var b = "";
    var c = "";
    var d = "";
    a += x;
    b += y;
    c += z;
    d += (x + y + z);
}
```

What would happen is, instead of `a` being equal to `1`, `b` being equal to `2`, and `c` being equal to `3`, they would all equal to undefined. I don't know why that is happening when `x`, `y`, and `z` are global variables. I thought they should change when set to a different value.

Here is my actual code:

```
var seconds;
var accurateclicks;
var inaccurateclicks;
var windowheight = window.innerHeight;
var windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
var colors = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Purple"];
var randomcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];

function BeginGameLoad(){
    var BottomLabel1 = document.getElementById("bl1");
    var BeginGameContainer = document.getElementById("BGC1");
    var RightClick = false;
    BottomLabel1.addEventListener("mousedown", BL1MD);
    BottomLabel1.addEventListener("mouseup", BL1MU);
    BottomLabel1.style.cursor = "pointer";
    window.addEventListener("resize", BeginGameResize);
    window.addEventListener("contextmenu", BeginGameContextMenu);
    function BeginGameContextMenu(e){
        if(e.which == 3 || e.button == 2){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    function BL1MD(e){
        if(e.which == 3 || e.button == 2){
            e.preventDefault();
            RightClick = true;
        }
        else{
            var randomcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
            BottomLabel1.style.color = randomcolor;
            RightClick = false;
        }
    }
    function BL1MU(){
        if(RightClick == false){
            window.location.href = "Game.html";
            GameLoad();
        }
        else{
            RightClick = false;
        }
    }
    if(windowheight < 600)
    {
        BeginGameContainer.style.height = "600px";
    }
    if(windowwidth < 800)
    {
        BeginGameContainer.style.width = "800px";
    }
    function BeginGameResize(){
        windowheight = window.innerHeight;
        windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
        if(windowheight <= 600)
        {
            BeginGameContainer.style.height = "600px";
        }
        if(windowheight > 600)
        {
            BeginGameContainer.style.height = "100%";  
        }
        if(windowwidth <= 800)
        {
            BeginGameContainer.style.width = "800px";
        }
        if(windowwidth > 800)
        {
            BeginGameContainer.style.width = "100%";  
        }
    }
}
function GameLoad(){
    var LeftPanel2 = document.getElementById("lp2");
    var LeftColorPanel2 = document.getElementById("lcp2");
    var TopPanel2 = document.getElementById("tp2");
    var TopLabel2 = document.getElementById("tl2");
    var RightPanel2 = document.getElementById("rp2")
    var RightLabel2 = document.getElementById("rl2");
    var GameContainer = document.getElementById("GC2");
    var MiddleLabelTwo = document.getElementById("mltwo3");
    var MiddleLabelThree = document.getElementById("mlthree3");
    var MiddleLabelFour = document.getElementById("mlfour3");
    var MiddleLabelFive = document.getElementById("mlfive3");
    var clickedRightName = false;
    var clickedRightColor = false;
    var clickedRightNameColor = false;
    var RightClick = false;
    var ClickedLeftColorPanel = false;
    var ClickedRightLabel = false;
    var ClickedTopLabel = false;
    var Timer;
    TopPanel2.addEventListener("mouseup", TP2MU);
    TopLabel2.addEventListener("mousedown", TL2MD);
    TopLabel2.addEventListener("mouseup", TL2MU);
    TopLabel2.style.cursor = "pointer";
    LeftPanel2.addEventListener("mouseup", LP2MU);
    LeftColorPanel2.addEventListener("mouseup", LCP2MU);
    LeftColorPanel2.addEventListener("mousedown", LCP2MD);
    LeftColorPanel2.style.cursor = "pointer";
    RightPanel2.addEventListener("mouseup", RP2MU);
    RightLabel2.addEventListener("mouseup", RL2MU);
    RightLabel2.addEventListener("mousedown", RL2MD);
    RightLabel2.style.cursor = "pointer";
    window.addEventListener("resize", GameResize);
    window.addEventListener("contextmenu", GameContextMenu);
    function AddSeconds(){
        seconds++;
    }
    function GameContextMenu(e){
        if(e.which == 3 || e.button == 2){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    function TL2MD(e){
        if(e.which == 3 || e.button == 2){
            e.preventDefault();
            RightClick = true;
        }
        else if(clickedRightName == true && clickedRightColor == true && clickedRightNameColor == true){
            TopLabel2.style.color = randomcolor;
            RightClick = false;
        }
    }
    function TP2MU(){
        if(ClickedTopLabel == false){
            inaccurateclicks++;
        }
        else{
            ClickedTopLabel = false;
        }
    }
    function TL2MU(){
        ClickedTopLabel = true;
        if(clickedRightName == true && clickedRightColor == true && clickedRightNameColor == true && RightClick == false){
            clearInterval(Timer);
            accurateclicks++;
            window.location.href = "EndGame.html";
            EndGameLoad();
        }
        else if (!clickedRightName == true && !clickedRightColor == true && !clickedRightNameColor == true && RightClick == false){
            clearInterval(Timer);
            Timer = setInterval(AddSeconds, 1000);
            seconds = 0;
            accurateclicks = 0;
            inaccurateclicks = 0;
            TopLabel2.innerHTML = randomcolor;
            RightClick = false;
        }
        else{
            inaccurateclicks++;
        }
        RightClick == false
    }
    function LCP2MD(e){
        if(e.which == 3 || e.button == 2){
            e.preventDefault();
            RightClick = true;
        }
        else{
            RightClick = false;
        }
    }
    function LCP2MU(){
        ClickedLeftColorPanel = true;
        if(clickedRightColor == false && TopLabel2.innerHTML != "Click Here To Start" && RightClick == false){
            var randomcolor2 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
            while (randomcolor2.toLowerCase() == LeftColorPanel2.style.backgroundColor){
                randomcolor2 = null;
                randomcolor2 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
                if(randomcolor2.toLowerCase() != LeftColorPanel2.style.color){
                    LeftColorPanel2.style.backgroundColorr = randomcolor2;
                    accurateclicks++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(randomcolor2.toLowerCase() != LeftColorPanel2.style.backgroundColor){
                LeftColorPanel2.style.backgroundColor = randomcolor2;
                accurateclicks++;
            }
            if (LeftColorPanel2.style.backgroundColor == randomcolor.toLowerCase()){
                clickedRightColor = true;
                LeftColorPanel2.style.cursor = "auto";
            } 
            randomcolor2 = null;
            RightClick = false;
        }
        else if(clickedRightColor == true && RightClick == false){
            inaccurateclicks++;
        }
    }
    function LP2MU(){
        if(ClickedLeftColorPanel == false){
            inaccurateclicks++;   
        }
        else{
            ClickedLeftColorPanel = false;
        }
    }
    function RL2MD(e){
        if(e.which == 3 || e.button == 2){
            e.preventDefault();
            RightClick = true;
        }
        else{
            RightClick = false;
        }
    }
    function RL2MU(){
        ClickedRightLabel = true;
        if(clickedRightName == false && TopLabel2.innerHTML != "Click Here To Start" && RightClick == false){
            var randomcolor2 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
            while (randomcolor2 == RightLabel2.innerHTML){
                randomcolor2 = null;
                randomcolor2 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
                if(randomcolor2 != RightLabel2.innerHTML){
                    RightLabel2.innerHTML = randomcolor2;
                    accurateclicks++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(randomcolor2 != RightLabel2.color){
                RightLabel2.innerHTML = randomcolor2;
                accurateclicks++;
            }
            if (RightLabel2.innerHTML == randomcolor){
                clickedRightName = true;
            }
            randomcolor2 = null;
        }
        else if(clickedRightName == true && clickedRightNameColor == false && RightClick == false){
            var randomcolor2 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
            while (randomcolor2.toLowerCase() == RightLabel2.style.color){
                randomcolor2 = null;
                randomcolor2 = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
                if(randomcolor2.toLowerCase() != RightLabel2.style.color){
                    RightLabel2.style.color = randomcolor2;
                    accurateclicks++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(randomcolor2.toLowerCase() != RightLabel2.style.color){
                RightLabel2.style.color = randomcolor2;
                accurateclicks++;
            }
            if (RightLabel2.style.color == randomcolor.toLowerCase()){
                clickedRightNameColor = true;
                RightLabel2.style.cursor = "auto";
            }
            randomcolor2 = null;
        }
        else if(clickedRightName == true && clickedRightNameColor == true && RightClick == false){
            inaccurateclicks++;
        }
    }
    function RP2MU(){
        if(ClickedRightLabel == false){
            inaccurateclicks++;
        }
        else{
            ClickedLeftColorPanel = false;
        }
    }
    if(windowheight < 600)
    {
        GameContainer.style.height = "600px";
    }
    if(windowwidth < 800)
    {
        GameContainer.style.width = "800px";
    }
    function GameResize(){
        windowheight = window.innerHeight;
        windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
        if(windowheight <= 600)
        {
            GameContainer.style.height = "600px";
        }
        if(windowheight > 600)
        {
            GameContainer.style.height = "100%";  
        }
        if(windowwidth <= 800)
        {
            GameContainer.style.width = "800px";
        }
        if(windowwidth > 800)
        {
            GameContainer.style.width = "100%";  
        }
    }
}
function EndGameLoad(){
    var BottomLabel3 = document.getElementById("bl3");
    var EndGameContainer = document.getElementById("EGC3");
    var MiddleLabelTwo = document.getElementById("mltwo3");
    var MiddleLabelThree = document.getElementById("mlthree3");
    var MiddleLabelFour = document.getElementById("mlfour3");
    var MiddleLabelFive = document.getElementById("mlfive3");
    var RightClick = false;
    BottomLabel3.addEventListener("mousedown", BL3MD);
    BottomLabel3.addEventListener("mouseup", BL3MU);
    BottomLabel3.style.cursor = "pointer";
    window.addEventListener("resize", EndGameResize);
    MiddleLabelTwo.innerHTML += seconds;
    MiddleLabelThree.innerHTML += accurateclicks;
    MiddleLabelFour.innerHTML += inaccurateclicks;
    MiddleLabelFive.innerHTML += seconds + accurateclicks + inaccurateclicks;
    window.addEventListener("contextmenu", EndGameContextMenu);
    function EndGameContextMenu(e){
        if(e.which == 3 || e.button == 2){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
    function BL3MD(e){
        if(e.which == 3 || e.button == 2){
            e.preventDefault();
            RightClick = true
        }
        else{
            randomcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
            BottomLabel3.style.color = randomcolor;
            RightClick = false;
        }
    }
    function BL3MU(){
        if(RightClick == false){
            MiddleLabelTwo.innerHTML = "Time (Seconds): "
            MiddleLabelThree.innerHTML = "Accurate Clicks: "
            MiddleLabelFour.innerHTML = "Inaccurate Clicks: "
            MiddleLabelFive.innerHTML = "Score: "
            window.location.href = "Game.html";
        }
    }
    if(windowheight < 600)
    {
        EndGameContainer.style.height = "600px";
    }
    if(windowwidth < 800)
    {
        EndGameContainer.style.width = "800px";
    }
    function EndGameResize(){
        windowheight = window.innerHeight;
        windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
        if(windowheight <= 600)
        {
            EndGameContainer.style.height = "600px";
        }
        if(windowheight > 600)
        {
            EndGameContainer.style.height = "100%";  
        }
        if(windowwidth <= 800)
        {
            EndGameContainer.style.width = "800px";
        }
        if(windowwidth > 800)
        {
            EndGameContainer.style.width = "100%";  
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I run it, it works up to this point

```
MiddleLabelTwo.innerHTML += seconds;
MiddleLabelThree.innerHTML += accurateclicks;
MiddleLabelFour.innerHTML += inaccurateclicks;
MiddleLabelFive.innerHTML += seconds + accurateclicks + inaccurateclicks;
```

It says seconds, accurateclicks, and inaccurateclicks are all undefined. I don't know why this would happen given that they were defined in the previous function [Game()].

Comment: which runs before which?? `A()`  before `B()` or the other way?

Comment: please add what you really want, with context.

Comment: Yes A() goes first

Comment: Works as expected http://plnkr.co/edit/fWQNNIxZ1zUjlZXqWNgG?p=preview

Comment: Your example is actually working as intented https://jsfiddle.net/f1frrjzv/. Perhaps the problem was how you `declared` these variables in your actual code

Comment: @masterpreenz I need to like you the original code, then. It isn't working.

Comment: @hansmaad here is my code: https://jumpshare.com/b/pvYdm95DIZbWOqOoQNJt#

Comment: @masterpreenz Here is my code https://jumpshare.com/b/pvYdm95DIZbWOqOoQNJt#

Comment: If that doesn't work, try this: http://jmp.sh/b/pvYdm95DIZbWOqOoQNJt

Comment: it is better to rewrite your question with your actual problem and not the example one, there explain what is going on.

Comment: @masterpreenz I put my js in the problem. The reason I don't at first is I usually get yelled at for dumping code into the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try writing,

```js
x = 1;
y = 2;
z = 3;

function A() {
  B();
}

function B() {
  var a = "";
  var b = "";
  var c = "";
  var d = "";
  a += x;
  b += y;
  c += z;
  d += (x + y + z);

  console.log(a, b, c, d);
}
A();
```

**Reason: 'var' defines variables locally!**

Comment: The way i did it is referring to the original code. I can't do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

You did make two html files and this caused the js file to reload. This is why the global variables are declared again and are renewed to undefined.The solution is to work with one html file and to only reload the body.

Comment: I need all 3 html files.

Comment: you can just make one main and make two body-only files which you can then replace into each other. But reloading with every file is the reason that you lose your variables.

Comment: What's a body-only file and how do i replace it?

Comment: Keep one file. Change the other two to only the code within the body-tags (without the body-tags itself). Then instead of reloading a file. Use jquery and do this: `$("body").load("secondfile.html");`

Comment: do you have the js equivalent?

Comment: `var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'somepage.html', true);

request.onload = function() {
  if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    var resp = request.responseText;

    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = resp;
  }
};

request.send();` This should work when running on localhost.

Comment: I just figured out an easier way. Just use localStarage

Answer (score 0):

My syntax was right, but as @Julie mentioned, the variables were being reloaded. [How to get JS variable to retain value after page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh) this helped me solve my problem.