# Storing wordle user gameplay

Tags: javascript, cookies, single-page-application

I am building a simple quiz game in JS/CSS. Curious about how wordle stores the streak statistics. Is it in the cookies?
Also, I want users to be able to access previous games and also their attempts. Is it possible to do it without having them create an account?

Comment: Look into local storage and session storage.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get JS variable to retain value after page refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206322/how-to-get-js-variable-to-retain-value-after-page-refresh)